# Inline column's getting pushed down

Tags: html, css

I have a 40% and a 60% inline column but for some reason when I put content in it one of the containers get's pushed down. Does anyone know why this would be happening?

### [Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3qk8fm15/)

HTML

```
<div class="grid">
    <div class="long-col">a</div>
    <div class="small-col">
        <div style="font-size:18px;width:100%;">a</div>
        <div style="font-size:18px;width:100%;">b<div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.grid { font-size:0px;}
.grid .long-col { 
    display:inline-block;
    width:40%;
    height:500px;
    background-color:green;
}
.grid .small-col {
    display:inline-block;
    width:60%;
    height:500px;
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

Comment: @brayn always use `vertial-align` property width `display: inline-block` to avoid such problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `vertical-align` `top`

```
.grid .long-col {
    background-color: green;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 500px;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 40%;
}
.grid .small-col {
    background-color: yellow;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 500px;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 60%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Add `float: left;` ins your `.grid .long-col` 
It is only happened because you use extra div in your `.grid .small-col` so add `float: left;` ins your `.grid .long-col`